# Sorting in kendogrid not on the data in current pagination, but the complete data fetched from database

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-grid

In kendo-grid there is option to sort the column data by clicking on column header, but sort is applied on only the current page data.
Suppose I fetched 100 records from database, and choose to keep pagination of 10 records at a time on GUI,so that at a time we can see 10 records on the webpage.
Now, my requirement is to apply sort not on only 10 records, rather all fetched record.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: try the server paging and server sorting as shown in this demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding

Comment: Its working, but i have a doubt over here that, after using server sorting,  kendo sends a request to the server after click on any column header. I watched this through firebug mozilla plugin that http request now contains two values, one for the column name and other sorting order. However the request parameter for these two values are generated by kendo itself. I doubt that is those parametere names fixed for that particular column or it can change? Second, is there any way to provide our own parameter, which holds some business meaning?

Comment: That request is all managed by the grid, so you don't have to do anything in addition to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server sorting is the only way to go. Please check this:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverSorting

Comment: Its working, but i have a doubt over here that, after using server sorting,  kendo sends a request to the server after click on any column header. I watched this through firebug mozilla plugin that http request now contains two values, one for the column name and other sorting order. However the request parameter for these two values are generated by kendo itself. I doubt that is those parametere names fixed for that particular column or it can change? Second, is there any way to provide our own parameter, which holds some business meaning?